# spring-data-redis use hashes instead of string even after configuring StringRedisTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

i want to use StringRedisTemplate with spring data redis.
Even after configuring StringRedisTemplate as RedisTemplate bean, Repository creates hashes.

```
@Bean
  public RedisTemplate redisTemplate() {
    StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate(jedisConnectionFactory());

    return template;
  }
```

Comment: RedisTemplate does not change anything about the repository output. Share more details like which function is used to push data etxc

Comment: crudRepository implementation for redis uses hashCommands. How can i configure it use StringCommands?